# How to add proxy_pass_header parameter in nginx udp loadbalancer to preserver destination ip

Tags: c, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have created a client-server application in C. My client resides on different VM and server resides on different VM.
On server side I am using Nginx load balancer, nginx load balancer accepts request from client and then sends request to respective containers but when loadbalancer send requests to container it modifies its header(i.e source ip and destination ip) and at container when I fetch destination ip from packet is gives container ip as destination ip, what I want is how we get actual destination ip from the packet.

```
Client IP : 192.x.x.x
Server IP : 192.x.x.y

Loadbalancer IP : 172.17.x.x
Container IP : 172.17.x.y

Flow :
client -> loadbalacer -> container

Client Sends Header (src : 192.x.x.x, dst 192.x.x.y)
Loadbalancer Recvd Header (src : 192.x.x.x, dst 192.x.x.y)
Loadbalancer Sends Header (src 172.17.x.x, dst 172.17.x.y)
Container Recvd Header (src 172.17.x.x, dst 172.17.x.y)
```

What I am actually looking for :

```
Loadbalancer Sends Header (src 192.x.x.x, dst 192.x.x.y)
Container Recvd Header (src 192.x.x.x, dst 192.x.x.y)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the load balancer is sending the request to the container, it is best to let the `src` be the IP of the load balancer.

In your container, to get the IP address of the client who initiated this request, look for the header [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) (in your case, this will be the IP `192.x.x.x`).

Comment: To preserver client IP or src IP I am already using proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent , which preserver client IP, but what I am looking for is how to preserver destination ip in loabalancer.